# Is there any way to implement HPA in kubernetes based on multiple pub/sub subscription?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling

I am using yaml to scale my service based on a single subscription which is "subcription1".
And I want to scale my service based on the list of subscriptions not on topic. Is there any way to solve it?

```yaml
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: demo-service-hpa
spec:
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - external:
      metricName: pubsub.googleapis.com|subscription|num_undelivered_messages
      metricSelector:
        matchLabels:
          resource.labels.project_id: <project-id>
          metadata.system_labels.subscription_id: subcription1 #I want to pass multiple subscription here
      targetAverageValue: "1"
    type: External
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: hpa-sample-service
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, but you can try to use the [API v2beta2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-multiple-metrics) which allows you to define several scaling metrics

> Kubernetes 1.6 adds support for scaling based on multiple metrics. You can use the autoscaling/v2beta2 API version to specify multiple metrics for the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler to scale on. Then, the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler controller will evaluate each metric, and propose a new scale based on that metric. The largest of the proposed scales will be used as the new scale

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [KEDA](https://keda.sh/) and its [Pub/Sub scaler](https://keda.sh/docs/1.5/scalers/gcp-pub-sub/).

> The Google Cloud Platform‎ (GCP) Pub/Sub trigger allows you to scale based on the number of messages in your Pub/Sub subscription.